# How to get access to this.props.location in child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new in React, so please dont get mad on me.  I have child component `<BottomSlider />` and I can't get access to `this.props.location`. I'm tried to console this.props and it shows only store, but in parent component it shows `history, location , store , match`. How I can pass location props to my `<BottomSlider>` component?

parent component

```
export default class Worklist extends Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <>
        <BottomSlider />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

and child component

```
export default class BottomSlider extends Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    // const { pathname } = this.props.location
    const { Modal } = this.props.store
    const { BuildingData } = this.props.store
    console.log("==============")
    console.log("test", this.props)

    return (
      <div
        className={`bottom-slider ${
          pathname !== "/worklist-dynamic"
            ? "bottom__slider-hide"
            : "bottom__slider-align"
        }`}
      >
        <div
          className={`bottom__slider ${
            pathname === "/worklist-dynamic" ? "bottom__slider-align" : "" // todo add visibility
          }`}
        >
      <div className="building_name">
        <p className="building_name-text">test</p>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: or you can pass all props to you component like `<BottomSlider {...this.props}/>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react router v4, you can add withRouter from react-router-dom in the child component to get access to the location in child component like the following:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom' 

export default withRouter(BottomSlider)
```